# What can a debugger do with /proc that cannot be done with ptrace?

Tags: performance, proc, debugging, system-calls, ptrace

The [Wikipedia article on ptrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace) says:

> Communications between the controller and target take place using repeated calls of ptrace, passing a small fixed-size block of memory between the two (necessitating two context switches per call); this is acutely inefficient when accessing large amounts of the target's memory, as this can only be done in word sized blocks (with a ptrace call for each word).[7] For this reason the 8th edition of Unix introduced procfs, which allows permitted processes direct access to the memory of another process - 4.4BSD followed, and the use of /proc for debugger support was inherited by Solaris, BSD, and AIX, and mostly copied by Linux

Is faster memory access the only thing that a debugger would care about that `/proc` allows but which is not possible with `ptrace`? For example, is there more debugger-relevant information about the running program available through `/proc`? What about additional debugger-relevant ways to manipulate programs? Would `/proc` be generally more efficient than `ptrace`, or is reading large blocks of memory the only noticeably less performant case?

Answer (score 2):

If the debugger likes to access the other process via `ptrace()`, it can only access a machine word at a time using an expensive system call per word.

Procfs on the other side provides `/proc/<pid>/as` which is the whole address space of the process seen in a file. On that file, `read()`, `write()` and `lseek()` work and this makes access to the other process faster.

But procfs also gives more information about the process than `ptrace()` that only delivers registers and address space access, as well as features like singlestep and similar.

The `truss(1)` utility was written by Roger Faulkner as part of the procfs. This is based on another interface that has been unique to procfs in 1986, but SunOS did enhance the `ptrace()` system call in 1988 to offer the the same functionality without a need to have procfs. SunOS did call the related program `trace(1)`.

Procfs also offers `/proc/<pid>/psinfo` for the `ps` command. Beforeprocfs was available, `ps` did read `/dev/kmem` to print information about the process and the way such information is retrieved makes it unreliable.

BTW: if you like to single step another process via procfs, this is done via an `ioctl()` ona file from procfs, while `ptrace()` offers a subcommand as a system call to do the same. Today `ptrace()` is implemented as a libc wrapper around procfs features.

Also note that Solaris not only offers the procfs, but Sun Microsystems did also hire **Roger Faulkner** the inventor of procfs. This is where he developed amongst others **procfs2**.

What Linux offers as procfs is neither compatible to **procfs1** nor to **procfs2**.

To check that Solaris implements ptrace via procfs,see: https://sourceforge.net/p/schillix-on/schillix-on/ci/default/tree/usr/src/lib/libc/i386/sys/ptrace.c

Comment: The wikipedia article I liked goes on to say that Solaris implements `ptrace` with `/proc`, but you're saying that this is broadly true of other Unix-likes as well? Interesting. Just to make sure I understand, would a fair summry be that `/proc` allows doing everything `ptrace` can do, plus some other things like information for the `ps` command, and possibly other features, but it will depend on the particular OS we're talking about?

Comment: Solaris does, see the pointer the source. Whether other OS do the same depends on whether they are based on SVr4 or not.